# DynamoDB unmarshall only unmarshalling one Map when multiple exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, unmarshalling

I am having trouble with unmarshalling information i'm retrieving from my DynamoDB table. This is t e raw format of it.

```
{
  "email": {"S": "example@example.com"},
  "name": {"S": "John Doe"},
  "clientConfiguration": {
    "M": {
      "chartTimeScale": {
        "S": "Periodic"
      },
      "naming": {
        "S": "Site"
      }
    }
  },
  "clientName": { "S": "Client" },
  "clientStatus": {"S": "Onboarding" },
  "createdDate": {"S": "2023-09-19T15:46:09.688Z"},
  "pageAccess": {
    "M": {
      "pageOne": {
        "BOOL": false
      },
      "pageTwo": {
        "BOOL": false
      },
      "pageThree": {
        "BOOL": false
      },
      "pageFour": {
        "BOOL": false
      },
      "pageFive": {
        "BOOL": false
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "L": []
  }
}
```

When i run this through the `unmarshall(data)` I get the following:

```
{
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "clientConfiguration": {
        "chartTimeScale": "Periodic",
        "naming": "Site"
    },
    "clientName": "Client" ,
    "clientStatus": "Onboarding" ,
    "createdDate": "2023-09-19T15:46:09.688Z",
    "pageAccess": {
        "M": {
            "Lifts": {
                "BOOL": true
            },
            "Roofs": {
                "BOOL": true
            },
            "HVAC": {
                "BOOL": true
            },
            "Refrigeration": {
                "BOOL": true
            },
            "Car Parks": {
                "BOOL": true
            }
        }
    },
    "users": []
}
```

I've tried using the unmarshall tool and creating my own version. but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea why and if so how to solve this. I'm using NodeJs

Comment: Strange that it would not unmarshall maps at the same level. Which SDK version is this?

Comment: I'm using the aws-cli/2.13.16

Comment: You mentioned unmarshall so you must be using an AWS SDK, not the awscli.

Comment: Your correct, I'm using the SDK, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to solve this issue is to use the [Document Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/classes/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.DynamoDBDocumentClient.html), which abstracts you from the type descriptors that DynamoDB uses completely.

You can learn more from this blog:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

As you show two completely different items it's hard to tell what the issue is, but my assumption is that you've double marshalled the item while saving it.

Comment: This is what I have been using:
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

// AWS access keys
const credentials: Credentials = {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID as string,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string,
};

// DynamoDB client
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(new DynamoDBClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials,
}));
This is why I'm confused as to why it's not working‍♂️

Comment: In that case it's not working because you saved double marshalled JSON. Go have a look at the item in the console under the JSON view, my bet is that you still see the type descriptors.